# GLS estimator of a VAR process

Tags: self-study, vector-autoregression, generalized-least-squares

I'm studiying how to derive the GLS estimator of a VAR process. I have studied the basics well, but I don't get the last passage here:[image]
Why the product can be rewritten as a quadratic form? Intuitively I know it is correct, but I can't remember a basic relationship that can justify the final result. I hope that somebody can explain!

Comment: Hint: symmetry and idempotency

Comment: Which of the equations do you find problematic?

Comment: The one before the last result... The property that links the final result with the previous passage

Comment: You just factor out Y to the left and to the right.

Comment: By the way, this is OLS, not GLS